# Writing Unicode to file in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to write a unicode string (in arabic) to a file in python.

```
f = codecs.open('out', 'w', "utf-8")
f.write(str(comment)+u'\n')
```

The lines written shows some characters such as:

> \xef\xbb\xbf

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which python version? In 2.7 `str` is not unicode, in 3.x it is.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, probably 2.x since the `u'\n'` was invalid between 3.0 and 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `str(comment)`. Use [unicode(object[, encoding[, errors]])](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) instead.